# Maximising each element in a matlab array

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to construct an array `A`, without looping, where `A(i,j) = max(B(i),C(j))` and `B` and `C` are column vectors?

Answer (score 2):

If the matrices are not too big, `repmat` could work:

```
B = [2 3];
C = [0 1 2 3];
% Vectorize the vectors for a simplication
B = B(:);
C = C(:);

A = max(repmat(B,1,length(C)),repmat(C',length(B),1));
```

For those interested, [Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat) and [Matlab - bsxfun no longer faster than repmat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722723/matlab-bsxfun-no-longer-faster-than-repmat) address its relative efficiency with respect to `repmat`. Apparently,  `bsxfun` used to be much faster, sometime ago. The difference seems shallower with the recent Matlab versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `bsxfun` if your version has it.

```
A = bsxfun(@max, B, C.')
```

As per their [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), `bsxfun` expands the dimensions of the argument matrices  on-the-fly, so does not use as much memory as `repmat`.

Comment: Nice reminder about `bsxfun`. For those interested, [Comparing BSXFUN and REPMAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719674/comparing-bsxfun-and-repmat) and [Matlab - bsxfun no longer faster than repmat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722723/matlab-bsxfun-no-longer-faster-than-repmat) address its relative efficiency with respect to `repmat`